# How to put statement before for-loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

How can one put statement before for-loop in python? Such as:

```
print i for i in range(10)
```

The above example may seems unnecessary. But when it comes to a more complicated generator, it might be handy and pythonic:

```
print i for i in takewhile(lambda x: x < 100000, fibonacci()) if i % 2 == 0
```

Of course the above statements would be complained by the interpreter. There should be some standard and simple way to do it, but I just can't find it. I know I can do something similar with list comprehension:

```
print [i for i in range(10)]
```

But it prints a list rather than every i in the list. Not exactly what I want.

Comment: What's the problem with a normal `for` loop?

Comment: How is putting both the statement and the complicated generator expression (= twice the complexity) into one line good?

Comment: Nothing wrong. I just have a preference with something succinct, especially one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't like the easy way?

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
```

If you *really* want the syntax you're talking about, you could try this:

```
from __future__ import print_function # Added in 2.6

map(print, range(10))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in Python.

You can put it after instead:

```
for i in range(10): print i
```

But usually you would write this on two lines.

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative:

```
print '\n'.join(map(str, range(10)))
```

Or a generator:

```
print '\n'.join(str(i) for i in range(10))
```